# difference between console log level and default log lovel

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

in module programming i read ,

if log level is

```
  less than console log level will get displayed and 
  higher than will be mentioned in log files ,
```

if i **dont specify any log level in printk statement then the default log level will be taken** .

i just saw the default and console log level

by

> cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk

and the result was

> 4 4 1 7

here both default and console was same .

i dont understand why default log level created . are we going to use the default log level in anywhere .

what is the exact difference between console log level and default log level .

i am new to module programming.

Answer (score 1):

As we know we have different kernel level logs:

```
#define KERN_EMERG "<0>" /* system is unusable*/
#define KERN_ALERT "<1>" /* action must be taken immediately*/
#define KERN_CRIT "<2>" /* critical conditions*/
#define KERN_ERR "<3>" /* error conditions*/
#define KERN_WARNING "<4>" /* warning conditions*/
#define KERN_NOTICE "<5>" /* normal but significant condition*/
#define KERN_INFO "<6>" /* informational*/
#define KERN_DEBUG "<7>" /* debug-level messages*/
```

Okay let us put for discussion separately:

**`Console log level`** is something which is used to set log levels that can be displayed on console window `with Log levels(printk) < Console log level`(4 taken considering wrt your case).

i.e., it will print kernel messages with printk using log levels from 0,1,2 and 3. rest 4 to 7 will be logged in circular buffer maintained by kernel - can be seen issuing `"dmesg"`.

Now if we move on to **`Default log level:`**

Whenever you use printk without any log level info, say for eg:

`printk("Insmod my first driver\n");` // this log level will be set to "kern_warning"(as default log level is 4).

So the difference is console log is used to decide what is needed to be printed on console and default log level is used for what log level is to be taken by default if not mentioned by `printk` during kernel module programming.

Comment: even i mentioned what are i knew before , why we are using two different values ,why we should not use the console log level instead of default log level

Comment: you mean tweaking printk behaviour, i think it is tiresome. why would one mess up console log level with default log level when two has its own definite roles. Console log is used to control what logs you wanted to see on console window - VT, whereas default log level is used to set loglevel when one fails to define loglevel in his print statement. Suppose if you wanted to put upto kernel level logs  3 on console and you are using different level say level 5 as default log level. then you would miss them(printk without loglevel mentioned) on console and find in dmesg buffer.